# default value of an select tag

Tags: java, html

I have the following problem: I want to establish a default value for my select tag, but the default value should be the result of an sql select statement; so I want to have a select filed with values from a table from a database, and the default value should be the result of an sql select statement from the same table....

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: How are generating HTML from Java?  I assume it's some server-side web apps framework like Struts?

Comment: I have an idea: <option value='...' selected>

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern for emitting a `<select>` while setting a default value from a database looks something like this (pseudo-code):

```
get data for select -> table
get default value -> defvalue

output "<select>"
for each row in table
    output "<option value=\"row.value\""
    if row.value = defvalue then output " selected"
    output ">" + row.description + "</option>"
next row
output "</select>"
```

The key here is that we conditionally include the `selected` attribute based on whether the current option row being printed happens also to be the default value retrieved from the database.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

my answer assumes you have some knowledge with JSP/Servlets or Ajax calls 
2 options:

1. when your DOM's ready (document-ready event), make an ajax call to the server to fetch the requested value (SQL query, in your case) to the client. When the value is returned in the ajax callback, set the relevant combo-box option 'selected' attribute.
2. if you have a JSP, make your SQL query, set the result to some java variable 'val', then assign it to the relevant option via the <%=val%> directive.